# How to distributed fetching a list of keys on s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-sdk, boto3

I am trying to distribute the process of getting a list of 60 million keys (file names) from s3.

**Background:** 
I am trying to process all files in a folder, about 60 million, via pyspark. As detailed [HERE](http://tech.kinja.com/how-not-to-pull-from-s3-using-apache-spark-1704509219) the typical sc.textFile('s3a://bucket/*') will load all of the data into the driver, and then distribute that to the cluster. The suggested method is to first acquire a list of files, parallelize the list, and then have each node fetch a subset of the files.

**Problem:** 
In this method there is still a bottleneck in the "acquire a list of files" step if that list is large enough. This step of getting a list of keys (file names) in an s3 bucket must also be distributed to be efficient.

**What Ive Tried:**
I have tried two different methods:

1. using the python aws api (boto3), which pages the results. Ideally we could estimate the number of pages, and distribute a range so that node 1 would request pages 1-100, node 2 would request pages 101-200, etc. Unfortunately you cannot specify an arbitrary page ID, you have to get the "next token" from the preceding page, aka a linked list of results.
2. The aws cli, in which they allow for exclude and include filters. As the file names I am retrieving all start with an 8 digit int I could, in theory, have node one request the full file list for files which match 10* and the second node to request the full file list for file names which match 11* etc. This is done by:

   aws s3 --recursive --exclude="*" include="10*" s3://bucket/

Unfortunately it seems to be doing a full scan every request instead of using some index since it hangs for > 15 minutes per request.

Is there a way to make either solution viable? Is there a third option? Im sure I am not alone in having millions of s3 files which need to be digested.

Comment: Is structure of all files same? If yes - then how we have have handled this is by creating a hive table on top of base s3 path and then we do our data manipulation/transformation using HQL or Spark SQL. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you, thats an interesting approach. yes, they are all json files with the same structure. I'll definately try that for analysis, but for now what I'm trying to do is search for errors in formatting, we had two sources, and an error which produced the wrong key in half of the documents. So it is a fix and resave effort.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a list of Amazon S3 content and you do not need it perfectly up-to-date, you could use [Amazon S3 Storage Inventory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which will store a daily CSV listing of all files in an S3 bucket. You could then use that list to trigger your pyspark jobs.

On a similar bent, you could maintain a database of all files, with a process to update the database whenever objects are added to/removed from the bucket by using [Amazon S3 Event Notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html). This way, the list is always up-to-date and accessible for your pyspark jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Prefix` parameter of [`list_objects_v2`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Paginator.ListObjectsV2) if your filenames will suffice as as a way to break up the files.